# How to reduce steps / line of code for this puzzle in python?

Tags: python

[Puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT5gK.png)
[Video Puzzle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19d4xQbH7R9qmPHv02BLyWnGcDKqiyaf0/view?usp=sharing)

Current Code:

```
for i in range(4):
    Dev.step(i+4)
    for a in range(3):
        Dev.step(i+2) 
        Dev.turnLeft()
    Dev.step(i+2)
```

From the puzzle it has to be 5 line of code. Currently I'am at 6 line of code. How do I make the code simpler ?.

The objective is to get all the Item (blue cylinder).

Comment: Replace all newlines with semicolons? The notion of "lines of code" is nebulous at best and downright foolish at worst, as a metric of code quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use semicolons, you can combine the `Dev.step(i+4)` and `Dev.step(i+2)` into a single line and changing the sequence of `Dev.turnleft()` and `Dev.step()` in the inner loop, so your resulting 5 line solution would something like -

```
for i in range(4):
    Dev.step(2*i+6)
    for a in range(3):
        Dev.turnLeft()
        Dev.step(i+2)
```

Comment: @rfl out of curiosity, what game is this?

Comment: It's from a website https://icode.org/hackathon/ . the puzzle that I'm playing is for practice and study about python as a beginner. It is similiar to Codementum